# Unable to upgrade from 13.04 to 14.04

Tags: 13.04, upgrade

I'm running Ubuntu 13.04, and would like to upgrade to 14.04.

Entering the following commands gives me output indicating that it cannot be done.

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 13.04
Release:    13.04
Codename:   raring
$ sudo do-release-upgrade 
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
No new release found
```

How can this be done?

(I have the ISO file for 14.04 too, if that makes a difference)

---

Update:

As per the sugestion below, I tried this, to no avail?

```
$ sudo do-release-upgrade -d
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
No new release found
```

---

Update:

Further investigation revealed that updates were not working too.

```
$ sudo apt-get update
# truncated
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Are there any software sources that still host raring (13.04)?

---

Update:

Editing the software sources to point to `old-releases.ubuntu.com` worked, enabling

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

To run as expected. However,

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

still yields the same result:

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
No new release found
```

Comment: 1. 13.04 is end of life. 2. You can **NOT** upgrade from 13.04 to 14.04. There is no skipping releases when upgrading. I would suggest a re-install (it's a lot quicker)

Comment: Weren't you asked to upgrade to 13.10 when it came out?

Comment: @Rinzwind actually, there is (was?) a way, but was disabled when 13.X and 12.10 went EOL.

Answer (score 21):

You are running Ubuntu 13.04. Ubuntu 13.04 has [reached it's end of life support on January 27th, 2014](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases), so you will not be able to do install/upgrade anything right now, that's why your `apt-get update` command is not working.

You should know that if you want to upgrade to 14.04, you have to follow the following upgrade order: 13.04 → 13.10 → 14.04.

1. You first need to edit your sources to use the "old releases" repositories. You can do this by running the following command:

   ```
   sudo sed -i -e 's/archive.ubuntu.com\|security.ubuntu.com/old-releases.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
   ```
2. Now, run the following:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
   ```

   This will upgrade all the packages to the latest available versions.
3. Now, try the Ubuntu upgrade:

   ```
   sudo do-release-upgrade -d
   ```

   This should work and prompt you to upgrade to 13.10. Do the upgrade, and then go through the same steps again to upgrade from 13.10 to 14.04.

In my opinion, it's just easier to do a fresh install of 14.04 using the ISO file you have, if you know how to do that, that is, and that there's not much data to backup.

Comment: Looks good. I too would re-install and go straight for 14.04.  13.04->13.10->14.04 takes a while (as in hours) and has 2 points of failures. A re-install does not imply formatting personal data: those files should already be on a sep. partition; if not I would start arranging that 1st).

Comment: Yeah I know =D, I was updating my answer as you were typing the comment. I always go for a fresh install anyways, but the poster might not know how to do a fresh install or a fresh install might not be so easy, especially if he's dual-booting and/or mounting `/home` on a different partition, because that would mean using the "Something else" option during installation, so I just wanted to mention the option of using the old-releases.

Comment: @AlaaAli Thanks for your answer, however this does not work for me. Changing software sources to point to `old-releases.ubuntu.com` worked, in that I was now able to successfully run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`. However, `sudo do-release-upgrade -d` still yields the same result: `No new release found`

Comment: Other issues I have 'solved': 1) comment-out all extras.ubuntu.com 2) I have also commented out all source repositories (may not be required) 3) comment out any archive.canonical.com repositories 4) change any country specific urls to 'US' repo. eg. au.old-releases.ubuntu.com to old-releases.ubuntu.com